# Automated update of image loading without changing html code

Tags: javascript, html

I have a web page containing photos and the following html code:

```
<table border="0"><tr>

<td width=20%>
<div class="thumbnails" align="top">

<img onmouseover="document.getElementById('preview').src=document.getElementById('img1').src"
alt="Image Not Loaded" id="img1" src="images/DC.jpg" />

<img onmouseover="document.getElementById('preview').src=document.getElementById('img2').src;"
id="img2" src="images/motel.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>

<img onmouseover="document.getElementById('preview').src=document.getElementById('img3').src"
id="img3" src="images/nicola.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>

</div>
</td>

<td width = 80%>
<div class="preview"><img id="preview"></div>
</td>

</tr>
</table>
```

What it does, it loads my images on the left of the page and as I hover on one, it displays it larger in the middle of the page. As I add new photos, I add a new line:

```
<img onmouseover="document.getElementById('preview').src=document.getElementById('img3').src"
id="img4" src="images/anotherpic.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
```

This can get tiresome. Is there a way to write code that does what I want without me needing to specify all the pics by simply looking in a folder? That way, I could simply drop a new image in the folder and after a page refresh I should see the new pic, and never have to touch my html code.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the parent node, 'thumbnails' this case, and then loop through all images in the node while adding the onmouseover function.

https://jsfiddle.net/z1p8jqoz/

```
var imgNodes = document.getElementsByClassName('thumbnails').childNodes;
for(i=0; i<imgNodes.length; i++) {

    console.log(imgNodes[i].src)
    var src = imgNodes[i].src

    function getMouseover(src) {
        return function(){
        document.getElementById('preview').src=src
       }
    }

    imgNodes[i].onmouseover =  getMouseover(src)
}
```

Comment: I am sure I am missing something easy, but I don't see how this works.

Comment: Ooops, forgot about scoping, the updated version should work properly. Check the fiddle if you're unsure

Comment: How does the page know what folder the pics are located in?

Comment: That depends on you backend. You'll need to scan the folder for images and add each image to the html, something like 
'for image in folder: html += "<img src=" + image.url + ">'

Comment: That was what I was asking. I have the code working, but I don't want to manually have to change the html code everytime I add a new image.